# Как работает деструктор std::allocator

Tags: c++

Допустим в ф-ции я создаю allocator, он распределяет память, потому деалацирует её, но представим что я забыл деалацировать какой-то отдельный кусок памяти, дак вот вопрос:
Когда allocator выходит из области видимости ф-ции, т.е. вызывается его деструктор, подчищает ли он ту память которую я забыл деалацировать?

И в чём разница между ф-циями deallocate() и destroy(), ведь результат один и тот же, память освобождается. Зачем вызывать destroy() уничтожать объект, если можно просто освободить память?

Answer (score 7):

`std::allocator` является аллокатором без состояния (stateless), а это значит, что его деструктор ничего не делает — он пустой. Всё, что выделено с помощью `allocate()`, должно быть освобождено с помощью `deallocate()`, в противном случае будет утечка памяти.

`deallocate()` и `destroy()` являются совершенно разными функциями: первая освобождает память, а вторая уничтожает объект. 
Вот как может выглядеть реализация функции `deallocate`:

```
template<typename T>
void std::allocator<T>::deallocate(T* ptr)
{
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

А вот пример `destroy`:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void std::allocator<T>::destroy(U* ptr)
{
    ptr->~T();
}
```

Как говорится: найди 10 отличий. Зачем уничтожать объект? Пусть у нас есть такой класс:

```
class SimpleMe
{
public:
    SimpleMe()
    {
        m_Resource = new int[100];
    }
    ~SimpleMe()
    {
        delete m_Resource;
    }
private:
    int* m_Resource;
};
```

Как думаете, если мы выделим память под этот объект, сконструируем его (`construct()`), а затем просто вызовем `deallocate()`, что тогда будет?

На каждый `allocate` должен быть вызван `deallocate`, на каждый `construct` должен быть вызван `destroy`.

Answer (score 3):

**destroy** вызывает деструктор объекта, а у объекта может быть очень много связей и информации. А память под этот объект ещё не освобождается. Полезно когда область видимости аллокатора ещё очень далеко, а объект сам по себе уже не нужен. Можно потом создать объект ещё раз под эту память с помощью **construct**.
**deallocate** освобождает *только* память под объекты, не вызывая деструкторы, это большая разница.